# Python tkinter delete tuple tag

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

On a tkinter window, I have a setup that has a grid, and whenever you click a square on the grid, the square changes color. If you click the same square again, the color changes back.

To do this however, I've just been painting over the same square with the same 2 colors, creating thousands of images after enough clicks.

To identify each grid square, I use the grid square's top left coordinate. I tried using tkinter tags by passing in the tuple of two coordinates (x, y) to a `create_rectangle` function, and then calling `canvas.delete(coords)`. However, this doesn't seem to work at all. It seems like when using

`canvas.create_rectangle(whatever, tags=coords)`

no matter what data type I make the coords, or whatever I do with them, tkinter seems to do something weird to them making me unable to delete them with any variation of

`canvas.delete(coords)`

Does anybody have a solution to this? I've been searching on the minimal tkinter documentation.
All I want is to delete a colored square on a grid, rather than paint over it again.

Here's some code to illustrate trying to delete a square using the same principle:

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
canvas_width = 850
canvas_height = 650

tCanvas = Canvas(master,
        width=canvas_width,
        height=canvas_height)

coordinates = (562, 130)
tkinterObject = tCanvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, fill='black', tags=(coordinates))
tCanvas.delete(coordinates)

tCanvas.pack()
mainloop()
```

In the example above, the square is not deleted.

Comment: See the example under "Patterns" at  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_rectangle-method and how it uses itemconfig and fill= to change the background color.

Comment: please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tags` attribute should be given a tuple of tags. The tag you are trying to create should be a tuple of the x and y coordinates. Thus, you need to give it a tuple of tuples.

Notice the use of a comma in the tags attribute in the following example, which guarantees that the data in the parenthesis is treated as a tuple. This isn't a tkinter thing, it's just how tuples work in python.

```
tag = (x,y)
canvas.create_rectangle(..., tags=(tag,))
```

That being said, you can get the item id of the item that was clicked on by using the tag `current`:

```
the_item = canvas.find_withtag("current")
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding a comma to the end of tags=coordinates, worked!

Just a note:  I had a grid and background behind the squares, so current would delete the grid and background too.